# converting mysql scripts to postgresql script

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following line in a .sql file from a mysql db:

```
  ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr TYPE VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL;
```

I would like to convert it into syntax that postgresql would understand.  In my personal tests, I was only able to get it to work by breaking it down into two separate statements, like so:

```
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr TYPE VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr SET DEFAULT NULL;
```

Just wondering if there's a way to consolidate the two statements back into one, but one that postgresql will be happy with?

Thanks!

Comment: You can leave out the `default NULL` in both cases.  That is the "default" default in both databases.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: OP is changing the data type. The column might already have a different default. If OP were just *adding* a column, you could drop the `default null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you posted is **not valid syntax at all**:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d610d)

To change the type in MySQL, you would use `CHANGE` or  `MODIFY`.
To change the default you would use `DROP DEFAULT` or `SET DEFAULT NULL`.

**If** the intention was to change the type and reset the column default:

[Like in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html), you can pack multiple actions into a single [`ALTER TABLE`statement in Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html) .

```
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr SET DEFAULT NULL
                  ,ALTER COLUMN ip_addr TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html#AEN67144)

> The main reason for providing the option to specify multiple changes
>   in a single `ALTER TABLE` is that multiple table scans or rewrites can
>   thereby be combined into a single pass over the table.

But if there was a `DEFAULT` on the column that is incompatible with the new type, you have to run two separate statements:

```
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr SET DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

Doesn't matter in this case anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I'm just trying to convert the sql shown here:  http://www.kamailio.org/wiki/install/upgrade/3.3.x-to-4.0.0

Comment: ah.. i guess i slightly modified it.  it's the fourth one down on the page.  But the bottom line is that I have to convert all that stuff into postgresql friendly syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gordon Linoff states in the comments, postgreSQL by default sets a value to null unless a value is given or the default is changed to something else;

therefore, all you'll need is:

```
ALTER TABLE lcr_gw ALTER COLUMN ip_addr TYPE VARCHAR(50);
```

Comment: Just that Gordon's comment *assumes* the column already has a default `DEFAULT`, which is unfounded AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

[The PostgreSQL ALTER TABLE syntax diagram](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html) doesn't show any way to combine changing a data type and changing a default value in a single SQL statement. You can't simply omit `set default null` in the general case. For example,

```
create table test (
  column_1 char(10) not null default 'a'
);
alter table test alter column column_1 type varchar(50);
insert into test values (default);
select * from test;
```

```
column_1
--
a
```

Instead, either rewrite as two independent statements (which you already know how to do), or as two statements in a single transaction.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Indeed. `[, . . .]` makes all the difference. More than once, I've read `where action is *one* of:` (emphasis added), and been caught by that. If I joined the PostgreSQL documentation project, maybe I could get that changed to "where action is one, or possibly more, of:". I'll delete this tomorrow. :-)